# Cello: playing D notes on A-string vs. D string

Tags: strings, cello, orchestral-strings

I'm a beginner to cello. On some cello cheat sheets. You can play the
`D note on A-string by holding down two fingers (in first position)`

But you can also play the `D note on the D-string without holding down any finger.`

So you do expect the notes sound identical using both method?

Comment: I think the question I posted is an exact duplicate of yours. [I've added an answer to it](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/129400/78419) to address "cheat sheets" that just use, say, the letter "D" rather than staff notation.

Comment: But I would ditch whatever source you're using if it tells you that "D on A string, in first position, is two fingers." That's C.

Comment: @Aaron The ukulele question is still about timbral differences between "the same [exact] note." The fingering described here makes it clear that this is about notes of the same pitch class but different octaves. Open D can not be played on A string except by scordatura.

Comment: @AndyBonner Thanks. I've retracted my close vote, since it was based on the wrong duplicate.

Comment: @Aaron Heh, though now you can't re-vote, can you?

Comment: @AndyBonner No, I'm out of the close-vote business on this one. Oh, well....

Comment: You can play the same D that is 4th finger first position on A string by going half-way up the D-string, or going 2/3 up the G string.   You aren't asking a clear question, and in any case if you can't hear a difference it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The A string is the highest string on the cello, the D string is the second highest. This means that the D you get on the A string (should be 4th finger in first position, not 2nd) is an octave above the empty D string. What would make sense is the difference between playing the empty A string or playing the A on the D string, which is in fact the same A. Here playing the same note on a lower string will change the response and tone color as will also allow for a wider vibrato.

Comment: Note, an early beginner probably won't be shifting. I don't think the question is about playing "the same" pitch on a different string.

Comment: I did not think so. I’ve included this remark as the comments and answers here all seem to suggest that this is the same note, just played on a thicker string, when it is not.

Answer (score 0):

The thicker the string, the mellower the tone.

Open strings will always sound different, and somehow seem to resonate better and longer.

It's only possible to apply vibrato to a stopped string, making the sound very different from an open one as well.

Comment: I don't think OP is asking about how to choose a certain fingering for a given pitch, but rather which octave to choose when only told a letter name. An exact dup of an old violin question.

Comment: @Andy Bonner - I wonder (as I often do, lonely as a cloud...) if OP is confused. And Lazy addressed the issue more accurately?

Comment: I think the clue is in "cheat sheet." I added an answer to my proposed dupe; I bet they're either reading off of a chord chart, or the sort of very-beginner notation that notates a melody using letter names and no indication of register (like the piece of paper that comes with purchase of a tin whistle and tells you how to play "Hot Cross Buns").

Comment: @AndyBonner - never come across 'cheat sheet', but listening to the octave of the notes *should* give a good clue as to whether they're up or down, surely.

Comment: Yup. Which is to say, yes, this OP and the one of the violin question are confused, probably because they're working from confusing material, like say trying to learn a tune given only letter names and no knowledge of how it's supposed to sound.

Answer (score -1):

No, they don't.  Playing on the D string is more mellow and especially so when you use the harmonic.  The A string has a brighter sound.

Comment: This question is not about playing the same pitch on two different strings; the OP is confused about how to choose which octave. The pitch played on D string "without holding down any finger" can not be replicated in any way on A string (except scordatura).

Comment: @AndyBonner that is not exactly true. If you get the D string to squeak you might be able to replicate the pitch on the A string.

Comment: @Lazy Hehe, I suppose so. how about "you can't get D3 out of a cello A string." Though there is an extended technique involving placing the bow on a harmonic node and bowing very heavily, that can produce a pitch lower than the normal open string. I'm not sure what the ratio is, I think maybe P4 below...